# Material-table: how to give custom style to EmptyDataSourceMessage

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Following this example:
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization

I would like to give custom style (basically color is my interest) to EmptyDataSourceMessage.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add HTML the the EmptyDataSource message using this in the render function:

```
const emailContact = <a href="mailto:myEmailAddressHere">Email Info</a>;
const noResultsMessage = <span>No results were found. Please email {emailContact</span>;
```

and then in the return method adding:

```
localization={{
    body: {
        emptyDataSourceMessage: noResultsMessage
    }
}}
```